# Pass Value of a component through arrow function method parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just have a project that i'm using react+typescript, and i have a simple question, i know there are multiple forms that i can pass values of a component through a arrow function parameter, but, i just search a lot and i can't find how can i make that:

```
<Button value={'1'} onClick={(e => SomeFunction(e.target))}>some text</Button>
```

The code inside the function, is something like that:

```
const SomeFunction = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
  }
```

I just want to pass to the Function, the value of the properties value, that is equal to '1', can you guys, help me?

Comment: There's no code inside that function... It'll do nothing! Well, maybe it could throw an error.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @ggorlen. I'm using e.target.value, but, what come using that , don't have the value of the button.

Comment: I just made a few changes in the question, but, the essential is in the question, I would just like to receive the value in my function, so that I can use it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead pass in the value as an argument into the function

```
<Button onClick={SomeFunction(1)}>some text</Button>
```

For a dynamic value you can do

```
['name'].map(val => (
  <Button onClick={SomeFunction(val)}>some text</Button>
))
```

Then on the function declaration

```
Const SomeFunction = value => event => {
   console.log(value) // 1
}
```

Comment: Yes, o just made that change on my code, but, i'm wondering when i have to pass a dynamic value of a component to my function, how i do that?

Comment: For a dynamic value pass in the value as an argument to the function like I did, It'll still work

Comment: @AndreiBaptista I just updated the answer to use a dynamic value

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> First take out the value property for the Button and pass it to the onClick function "SomeFunction('1')"

```
<Button onClick={(e => SomeFunction('1'))}>some text</Button>
const SomeFunction = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but, i'm very worried when i have to pass a  dynamic value of a component to my function.

Comment: if its an array of items, you could use the map method to pass every item dynamically to the button